# Word cannot start the converter mswrd632.wpc error

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, conversion

problem:
you try and open a word document and it produces the message

> Word cannot start the converter mswrd632.wpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is probably caused by a security update
see 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973904

but before that.. try and rename you .doc file to .docx

an incorrectly renamed file can also cause this error.

if you open teh renamed file and get junk.. then it was probably a binary file and this will not help.
rename it back again.

the support article lists this as a possible solution..

**Let me fix it myself**

> To unregister the mswrd632 converter yourself, edit the registry as follows:
>
> - Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
> - Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Text Converters\Import\MSWord6.wpc
> - On the Edit menu, click Delete.
> - Click Yes.
> - Exit Registry Editor.

Answer (score 2):

Might i suggest (if you're IT staff in an operational environment such as a service centre) that if a user calls up with this you ask them the following question...

Does the name of the document you are trying to open start with "~$" and is the icon pale and greyed out.

Yes, seriously.  I've had this error triggered a number of times by users trying to open temp files.  Point them to the correct file.  Accept their heartfelt thanks.